# how do break text to three different lines with dymo and the javascript library?

Tags: javascript, dymo

I have an address label I am setting up using the dymo javascript SDK, I am able to successfully print and all, but I am having trouble figuring out how to break my string value into three lines of text on the label

for instance, my string which is currently printing on one line: `PROJECT NAME ABC 1234 SOMETHING AVE (IN) CITY, ST 000000`

needs to be on three 
`12345 PROJECT NAME ABC`
`1234 SOMETHING AVE`
`(IN) CITY, ST 000000`

how do I break a string for printing it into three lines using dymos javascript library?

here is my label xml

```
var labelXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
   <DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips">\
    <PaperOrientation>Landscape</PaperOrientation>\
    <Id>Address</Id>\
    <PaperName>30252 Address</PaperName>\
    <DrawCommands>\
        <RoundRectangle X="0" Y="0" Width="1581" Height="5040" Rx="270" Ry="270" />\
    </DrawCommands>\
    <ObjectInfo>\
        <AddressObject>\
            <Name>Address</Name>\
            <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
            <BackColor Alpha="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" />\
            <LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>\
            <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>\
            <IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>\
            <IsVariable>True</IsVariable>\
            <HorizontalAlignment>Left</HorizontalAlignment>\
            <VerticalAlignment>Middle</VerticalAlignment>\
            <TextFitMode>ShrinkToFit</TextFitMode>\
            <UseFullFontHeight>True</UseFullFontHeight>\
            <Verticalized>False</Verticalized>\
            <StyledText>\
                <Element>\
                    <String>\
                    </String>\
                    <Attributes>\
                        <Font Family="Arial" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
                        <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
                    </Attributes>\
                </Element>\
            </StyledText>\
            <ShowBarcodeFor9DigitZipOnly>False</ShowBarcodeFor9DigitZipOnly>\
            <BarcodePosition>Suppress</BarcodePosition>\
            <LineFonts>\
                <Font Family="Arial" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
                <Font Family="Arial" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
                <Font Family="Arial" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
            </LineFonts>\
        </AddressObject>\
        <Bounds X="332" Y="150" Width="4455" Height="1260" />\
    </ObjectInfo>\
   </DieCutLabel>';
```

here is the javascript calling it

```
var label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);

var printIt = '142277 MARRIOT BURBANK AIRPORT HOTEL\
               2500 N. HOLLYWOOD WAY, 1ST FLOOR\
               (JH) BURBANK, CA 91505'

  var label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);
  label.setObjectText("Address", printIt);
  label.print("DYMO LabelWriter 450");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to put '\n' for each line break.
This worked for my problem.

```
var printIt = '142277 MARRIOT BURBANK AIRPORT HOTEL\n2500 N. HOLLYWOOD WAY, ST FLOOR\n(JH) BURBANK, CA 91505';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add various element to StyledText and add "\n" to every line. First you have to separate in lines with js.

```
    var lines = printIt.split('\');
    var lineOne = lines[0]; //for eg
```

And then you can add to your XML:

```
    <StyledText>\
     <Element>\
      <String>STYLE:' + lineOne + '\n' + ' </String>\
       <Attributes>\
        <Font Family="Arial" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
        <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
       </Attributes>\
     </Element>\
     <Element>\
      <String>STYLE:' + lineTwo + '\n' + ' </String>\
       <Attributes>\
        <Font Family="Arial" Size="10" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
        <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
       </Attributes>\
     </Element>\
    ...
    </StyledText>\
```